# Applying Filter on a disconnected ADODB Recordset in VBA

Tags: vba, adodb, recordset

I 've got a **disconnected** recordset which  can be copied to an Excel worksheet by method "CopyFromRecordset".
But before that I need to set a Filter on the recordset by Filter property:

```
Rst.Filter = "UnitPrice >100" 
Rst.MoveFirst 
Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset Rst
```

The code raises a run-time error of some Automation Error at "Rst.Filter..." line.
Is there something that I did wrong?! or simply we cannot apply filter to a disconnected recordset??!

Comment: That looks OK to me - maybe a little more code would be useful here.

Comment: Yes, can you show how you are opening the recordset please.

Comment: Look at the cursor location and type when opening the recordset.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Recordset is defined in a class module, and when object initiated, recordset created and opens. CursorLocation = adUseClient , CursorType = adOpenKeyset , LockType = adLockOptimistic are set before opening. Everything goes fine without filter.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing and searching, I could find the source of problem.
It was due to definition of data-type of fields appeneded to the recordset at the recordset creation time, which were all of type adVariant = 12 for ease.
Seems that this data type is no longer fully supported, and for filtering recordset, all data types of fields must be precisely defined at the creation and used properly in Filter string.  see the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum?view=sql-server-ver15